# \animategraphics cuts image

Tags: graphics, animate, ps2pdf, dvips

My image works perfectly with `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[height=1.0\textheight]{../../../movie/frinj_cII/movie20100}
```

but when I include it with `\animategrahics` ...

```
\animategraphics[height=1.0\textheight,loop]{10}{../../../movie/frinj_cII/movie2}{0100}{0100}
```

... approximately the lower half of the image is cut off.

Whats wrong ?

Comment: The last 2 arguments of `\animategraphics` must be set to blanks. See my answer.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ That is not entirely correct, the last 2 arguments are necessary when the formatting of the counters are not consecutive. Thus Holger have done it correct.

Comment: @Holger we probably need at least two images to figure out what goes wrong. Furthermore having images of different sizes could be the issue. It is not clear from the current information whether this is the case.

Comment: Are you animating graphics files in Postscript file format? If so, you are going the latex-->dvips-->ps2pdf workflow. Here you must not call dvips with option -Ppdf. See the **Bugs** section of animate doc.

Answer (score 3):

There are two pitfalls in using the `latex`-->`dvips`-->`ps2pdf` workflow. Both of them are explained in the **Bugs** section of the animate documentation.

1. The `dvips` option `-Ppdf` must be either omitted entirely or extended by appending option `-D1200`. This sets a sensible DVI resolution (which is only relevant for Type-3 pixel-font generation by MetaFont).

   Some (La)TeX-aware editors, such as TeXnicCenter use the `dvips` commandline option `-Ppdf` by default. Check the preferences of the editor.
2. The unscaled graphics must not exceed the document page dimensions. Otherwise parts of the graphics may be cropped away during `ps2pdf` conversion. Resize Postscript graphics files using the `epsffit` commandline tool as explained in the animate doc, if needed. `epsffit` is part of TeX-Live.

Comment: Excuse me, will you update the animate package to support spaces in the path as answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74508/19356)?