# How to make \animategraphics happy with a file name with spaces?

Tags: paths, animate

```
% this filename is main.tex
% compile it with "pdflatex -shell-escape main" (without the quotes)

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% Create a PDF file that consist of some pages
\begin{filecontents*}{"heart animation.tex"}
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\FPeval\Delta{round(2*pi/30:2)}

\def\x(#1){sin(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){(13*cos(t)-5*cos(2*t)-2*cos(3*t)-cos(4*t))/16}

\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=300}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.00+\Delta}{31}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psparametricplot[origin={0,0.15},linecolor=red]{0}{\n}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{latex "heart animation.tex"}
\immediate\write18{dvips "heart animation.dvi"}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf "heart animation.ps"}
% sometimes you need to disable auto rotate in ps2pdf. Please follow up if you really need it!
% delete auxiliary files generated by the 3 commands above.
\makeatletter
\@for\x:={tex,dvi,ps,log,aux,out,toc,nav,snm}\do{\immediate\write18{cmd /c if exist "heart animation.\x" del "heart animation.\x"}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
%\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=<integer>]{<frame rate>}{<PDF filename without extension>}{<left blank>}{<left blank>}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{10}{"heart animation"}{}{}
\end{document}
```

How to make `\animategraphics` happy with a file name with spaces?

Comment: Wouldn't renaming to `heart_animation` be a solution?

Comment: @tohecz: I want to create a bullet proof system that is more general for any possible cases.

Comment: Switching catcodes has all the problems of \verb you would not be able to use it inside another macro. If you do want to switch | to " just do something like \def\foo|#1|{"#1"}  then \foo|abc def| expands to "abc def"

Comment: Can you use simple quotes instead of double quotes in a `.bat` file?

Comment: What happens if you use package `grffile` and then a filename inside quotes: `"foo bar"`

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ In my experiment, `animategraphics` accepts spaces in a file name enclosed in double quotes, but instead of `heart animation` looks for `heartanimation`.

Comment: what happens with `...{heart\space animation}...`

Comment: @Herbert: It does not works. :-)

Comment: You can't present this bounty to AleXG if he doesn't answer this question anyway and I don't think you can invite him for community work with rep points. He is quite active anyway. Just contact him :)

Comment: @percusse: It is enough for me if he gives a short answer saying "the requested feature has been implemented". :-)

Comment: I have tried to incorporate Heiko 's and egreg 's code suggestions. Unfortunately, while embedded spaces will work, other things get broken. So I gave up with it. Spaces in file names remain evil.

Comment: @AlexG: What things get broken?

Comment: other engines (dvipdfmx, xetex), multipage input detection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `\animategraphics` uses LaTeX's `\IfFileExists` that uses the space as end marker of the file name. Then the result `\@filef@und` contains the file name including a final space. `\animategraphics` then removes the space via `\zap@space` that also kills spaces in between.

The following workaround redefines `\animategraphics`. It uses package `grffile` `\grffile@IfFileExists` instead of `\IfFileExists`, sets `\@filef@und` to the file name without the final space and neutralizes `\zap@space`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{org@animategraphics}{%
  \LetLtxMacro\org@animategraphics\animategraphics
  \renewcommand*{\animategraphics}{%
    \begingroup
    \@ifnextchar[{%
      \def\anigrf@opt{[}%
      \anigrf@animategraphics
    }{%
      \let\anigrf@opt\@empty
      \anigrf@animategraphics
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand{\anigrf@animategraphics}[5][]{%
    \renewcommand{\IfFileExists}[3]{%
      \grffile@IfFileExists{##1}{%
        \let\@filef@und\grffile@file@found
        \def\zap@space####1 \@empty{####1}%
        ##2%
      }{##3}%
    }%
    \ifx\anigrf@opt\@empty
      \org@animategraphics{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    \else
      \org@animategraphics[{#1}]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{10}{heart animation}{}{}%
\end{document}
```

### Update for animate 2013/04/23

Since 2013/04/23 (or before?) package `animate` supports quoting of file names
(thanks mozartstraße for the hint):

```
  \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{10}{"heart animation"}{}{}%
```

Thus the patch is not needed.
However, I think, quotes do not belong to the user interface, there are already curly braces to delimit the file name argument. Thus the following updated patch automatically adds quotes, if spaces are detected. If quotes are already given,
then the file name argument is not changed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{org@animategraphics}{%
  \LetLtxMacro\org@animategraphics\animategraphics
  \renewcommand*{\animategraphics}{%
    \begingroup
    \@ifnextchar[{%
      \def\anigrf@opt{[}%
      \anigrf@animategraphics
    }{%
      \let\anigrf@opt\@empty
      \anigrf@animategraphics
    }%
  }%
  \@ifpackagelater{animate}{2013/04/23}{%
    \def\anigrf@testspace#1 #2\@nil{%
      \def\anigrf@tmp{#2}%
    }%
    \def\anigrf@testquote#1"#2\@nil{%
      \def\anigrf@tmp{#2}%
    }%
    \newcommand{\anigrf@animategraphics}[3][]{%
      % do nothing if the file name contains quotes
      \edef\anigrf@file{#3}%
      \@onelevel@sanitize\anigrf@file
      \expandafter\anigrf@testquote\anigrf@file"\@nil
      \ifx\anigrf@tmp\@empty % file name without quote(s)
        % test for space in the file name
        \@firstofone{\expandafter\anigrf@testspace\anigrf@file} \@nil
        \ifx\anigrf@tmp\@empty % file name without space(s)
          % do nothing, no spaces found
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else % file name with space(s)
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
      \else % file name with quote(s)
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \fi
      {\anigrf@@animategraphics{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
      {\anigrf@@animategraphics{#1}{#2}{"#3"}}%
    }%
    \newcommand{\anigrf@@animategraphics}[5]{%
      \ifx\anigrf@opt\@empty
        \org@animategraphics{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
      \else
        \org@animategraphics[{#1}]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
      \fi
      \endgroup
    }% 
  }{%
    \newcommand{\anigrf@animategraphics}[5][]{%
      \renewcommand{\IfFileExists}[3]{%
        \grffile@IfFileExists{##1}{%
          \let\@filef@und\grffile@file@found
          \def\zap@space####1 \@empty{####1}%
          ##2%
        }{##3}%
      }%
      \ifx\anigrf@opt\@empty
        \org@animategraphics{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
      \else
        \org@animategraphics[{#1}]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
      \fi
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{10}{heart animation}{}{}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122082/19356).

Comment: @mozartstraße: Thanks, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For some reasons, `animate` doesn't like spaces in file names. In general they should be avoided whenever possible. What happens when you feed `\animategraphics` with the file name `"heart animation", the package tries to include`heartanimation.pdf`, removing spaces in the name.

A solution is to change the category code of the space before absorbing the second mandatory argument of `\animategraphics`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}

\newcommand{\myanimategraphics}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\myagtempopt{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \def\myagtempmand{\unexpanded{#2}}%
    \catcode`\ =12 \myanimategraphicsaux
}
\def\myanimategraphicsaux#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\animategraphics[\myagtempopt]{\myagtempmand}}%
  \x{#1}{#2}{#3}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\myanimategraphics{3}{"heart animation"}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will give you a bounty of 100 later.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ Don't worry: Heiko's answer deserves all credit.

Comment: The bounty of 100 has been awarded to [your another answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45502/19356).

Answer (score 1):

The latest `animate` package can accept a path with spaces but it must be enclosed with quotes.

As a result, Heiko Oberdiek's solution no longer works (it produces compilation errors).

Comment: Did you try different engines (`latex/dvips/ps2pdf`, `xelatex`, `pdflatex`, ...)?

Comment: @AlexG: It only works with `pdflatex`. It fails with `xelatex`. I don't test it with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`  because I don't think `\animategraphics` can import `dvi` or `ps`.

Comment: Of course, it can import Postscript in dvi mode, like `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @AlexG: It fails to compile with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`. All of my tests did not use Oberdiek's solution. I just use the `animate` package.